# Надо переставить динамический массив обратном порядке

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно переставить элементы массива в обратном порядке
Этот код вводит элементы массива

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n;
cin >> n;
int *a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Так вот я не могу понять как написать цикл который переставит элементы массива.Я только начал про массивы читать.
Вот  это я накалякал:

```
    for (int i = a[i]; i < n; i-- ) {
    a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
```

Дело в том что нельзя использовать reverse, swap.

Comment: Приведите код вашего решения задачи и что конкретно у вас не получается. Решать задачу за вас никто не будет.

Comment: щя поставлю я его удалил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В C++ есть стандартный алгоритм `std::reverse`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, который переставляет элементы контейнера в обратном порядке.

Вы могли бы записать

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::reverse( a, a + n );
```

Но, как я понимаю, вам самостоятельно нужно написать эту функцию. Определенная специально для целочисленных массивов, она может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void reverse( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n - i - 1];
        a[n - i - 1 ] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Размер массива лучше объявить как переменную типа `size_t` вместо `int`.

Вместо данного фрагмента кода

```
int tmp = a[i];
a[i] = a[n - i - 1];
a[n - i - 1 ] = tmp;
```

вы также могли бы воспользоваться стандартной C++ функцией `std::swap`. Например

```
std::swap( a[i], a[n - i - 1] );
```